# Is there a way to add the standard record detail component to a custom component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

We are wanting to add the standard `Record Detail` component to a custom Aura or LWC. Our goal is to be able to split the page into two columns using the grid system and place the standard `Record Detail` component on the left side and another custom component on the right side.

I realize I could do something like this with a page template, but my layout dictates that I have a full width layout, so I need a way to splitting the components inside of a tab pane.

Comment: can you make use of [record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) or [record-view-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-form/documentation)?

Comment: Unfortunately our users want the exact look/feel of the standard Record Detail form.

Comment: Are you saying that a `flexipage:template` that contains two `flexipage:region`s in it (left and right) where the standard record detail page can be dropped into the left region via the Lightning App Builder UI won't work for your use case? Where does it fall short?